# Cube spinning on its corner

Tags: html, css, 3d, css-transforms, rotatetransform

I have a 3D cube made from pure HTML-cum-CSS which is supposed to spin on one of its corners without the corner moving around the screen. Unfortunately, it doesn't quite do so, it rather wobbles along a line (2D) or around a circle (3D). What am I doing wrong?

```css
#cube {
    position: relative;
    margin: 100px auto;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    animation: 4s rotateforever infinite linear;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.face {
    position: absolute;
    height: 78px;
    width: 78px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: black 2px solid;
}

.one {
    transform: rotateX(-45deg) rotateY(45deg) translateZ(50px);
}

.two {
    transform: rotateX(-45deg) rotateY(135deg) translateZ(50px);
}

.three {
    transform: rotateX(-45deg) rotateY(225deg) translateZ(50px);
}

.four {
    transform: rotateX(-45deg) rotateY(315deg) translateZ(50px);
}

.five {
    transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateZ(-45deg) translateZ(50px);
}

.six {
    transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(-45deg) translateZ(50px);
}

@keyframes rotateforever {
    to {
        transform: rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="cube">
        <div class="face one">one</div>
        <div class="face two">two</div>
        <div class="face three">three</div>
        <div class="face four">four</div>
        <div class="face five">five</div>
        <div class="face six">six</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nph3k39p/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer:

According to a post on [Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41340) the left and right angle between the horizontal and the cube in its original position is not `45deg` (as I assumed), but only `35.2644deg`.

Therefore in my CSS, I had to change the values of each occurrence of a `transform: rotateX(...)` to `35.2644deg` where I used to have `45deg` and to `54.7356deg` (90 - 35.2644) where I used to have `-45deg`.

Like so:

```
.one {
    transform: rotateX(-54.7356deg) rotateY(45deg) translateZ(50px);
}

.two {
    transform: rotateX(-54.7356deg) rotateY(135deg) translateZ(50px);
}

.three {
    transform: rotateX(-54.7356deg) rotateY(225deg) translateZ(50px);
}

.four {
    transform: rotateX(-54.7356deg) rotateY(315deg) translateZ(50px);
}

.five {
    transform: rotateX(35.2644deg) rotateZ(-45deg) translateZ(50px);
}

.six {
    transform: rotateX(35.2644deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(-45deg) translateZ(50px);
}
```

I updated the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nph3k39p/1/).